# jquery validate form plugin using a selector not a form

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I had to refactor a web page when I added an image upload form nested within the main form as this is not possible. The outer form was converted into elements with an 'item' class and onClick of the submit button I serialised these using a selector

```
form = $(".item").serialize();
```

However I'm now refactoring again to use the jquery validate plugin and I'm wondering if I'm able to use this selector rather than the form itself (which is nolonger there) in some way.

I was thinking something like:

```
$(".item").validate(
{
   rules: {
         summary: {
              validateSummary: true
         }
    ..........etc etc
```

this doesn't seem to work but the theory was I'd serialize the matching '.item' elements and then apply custom validation to the elements in this list that matched the name (in the same way I assumed that a form serialization would work).

I've seen the classRules option that comes with the validate plugin however it looks like this groups custom validations by class, in fact I want to do 'normal' form validation only for this I use a selector instead of the #form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly can't follow the reasoning behind all of your DOM manipulations, but in this case, I don't have to.

To use the jQuery Validate plugin, your input elements *must* be inside of a set of  `form` tags.   There is no workaround for this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

One way to validate fields that have to be outside the form being submitted (for whatever reason - sometimes this is a good reason and sometimes it's not), would be to use a hidden field that is within your form, even if the real field you are interested in is outside the form.

Before validating, set the value of the hidden field to the value of the element outside your form. Then call the validate plugin on the form (like Sparky said, you must call it on the form), which will validate the hidden field if you have this ignore setting:

```
$('#myform').validate({
        ignore: [],
        // any other options and/or rules
    });
```